# Virtual Host check local website first instead of online site

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost

Hello i am using xampp on my local computer and i created virtual host like `www.abc.com` my original website have same name. Can i set priority of my virtual host instead of online site. For example i hit `www.abc.com` it checks local site ("Which is inside xampp") if no website found than go online.

Comment: Create a static name resolution entry on your local system (from where you test your sites) that resolves www.abc.com to your local system/server. That's all required, since in that case a local browser does not query the "normal" name resolution system, but uses the local resolution instead.

Comment: I am a newbie kindly little explain step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an entry in the host file of your OS. For Windows 7 it would be located in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host".

Add a line like this "127.0.0.1 abc.com"

But keep in mind that if you do that you will always access your localhost until you remove the line again.